# Why can't we define the Einstein Tensor in an easier way?

Tags: tensors

The Einstein tensor is defined as:

$G_{ab}=R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R$

where $R=g^{ab}R_{ab}$. So why can't we just simplify this like:

$G_{ab}=R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R=R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}g^{ab}R_{ab}=\frac{1}{2}R_{ab}$?

Comment: No.  Summation (contraction) doesn't occur over the metric tensors.  So it should look more like $$G_{ab} = R_{ab} -\frac 12 g_{ab}g^{cd}R_{cd}$$

Comment: What about:

$G_{ab}=g_{ab}g^{ab}R_{ab}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ab}R = g_{ab}(\frac{1}{2}R) $ since $g_{ab}g^{ab}$ is the identity why is this wrong?

Comment: My professor told me that both of the things I proposed are correct except that $g_{ab}g^{ab}=k$, the dimension of the manifold and not the 1 as it is the trace of the Identity so this would give in both cases $G_{ab}=g_{ab}(\frac{(2-k)R}{2k})$. Do you agree that this could be the case? I mean it makes sense to keep the dimension of the manifold out of the equation in defining the Einstein tensor..

Comment: The problem that I have with both of your propositions is what does $g_{ab}g^{ab}R_{ab}$ even mean?  When you have $1$ upper and $1$ lower index, you sum over because of the Einstein convention.  When you have three how do you sum over them?  Are you supposed to do $\sum_a \sum_b g_{ab}g^{ab}R_{ab}$ -- because that almost certainly won't equal $kR_{ab}$ (IDK what that would equal).  Are you supposed to do the $g_{ab}g^{ab}$ part first and then have $kR_{ab}$?  Or should you do the $g^{ab}R_{ab}$ part first to get $R^{ab}$, then sum over $g_{ab}R^{ab}$ to get $R_{ab}$?  It's too ambiguous.

Comment: There's a reason why the Einstein convention is only applied when you have *exactly* $1$ upper and $1$ lower index. -- Keep in mind, though, I'm not exactly an expert on tensor analysis.  If you professor says it's correct then maybe it is -- I just don't understand how.

Comment: I have seen definitions of Ricci scalar as $R_{ab}^{ab}$ which would be summing over two indices, however I am afraid I do not completely nderstand this either... I ll try to get some further explanation and update

Comment: Summing over two *separate* indices is not problem.  It's when you have $$a_ib^ic_i$$ that the ambiguity exists.  I probably should have said that the Einstein convention implies summation when you have $1$ upper and $1$ lower of *the same index*.  It doesn't matter if there are other indices there, too.